# Unity ads Never End. They Loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads

Hello my unity ads are working but don't stop when I click the close button it just loads another ad. How could I make it so it will stop playing after one ad and proceed with loading the menu?

I am VERY new to C# FYI.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

//GameOver page when the plane is destroyed
public class GameOverPage : MonoBehaviour {

public GUISkin skin; //skin for button styles
public static int start; //static integer indicates to show or hide Start/GameOver page
public static bool running; //static variable indicates if the plane is destroyed or not


void OnGUI(){
            GUI.skin = skin;

            //if start is not equal to 0 and running is false then show GameOver page buttons
            if ((StartPage.start != 0) && !PlaneMovement.running) {
        if (Advertisement.IsReady ()) {
            Advertisement.Show ();

        }



        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2.378f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6f, Screen.height / 10.10f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Restart"))) {  
                            Application.LoadLevel (1);  
                            PlaneMovement.running = true;
                    }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 1.50f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6.0f, Screen.height / 10.1f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Home"))) {
                            Application.LoadLevel (0);  
                            PlaneMovement.running = false;
                            StartPage.start = 0;
                    }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 5.7f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6f, Screen.height / 10.10f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Website"))) {
                            Application.OpenURL ("http://www.skyboxertech.weebly.com");
                    }


        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This is what i've got. Im not sure how to implement the timer it shows all the ads again in a loop and is not limiting them to every 5th time.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

//GameOver page when the plane is destroyed
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class GameOverPage : MonoBehaviour {

public GUISkin skin; //skin for button styles
public static int start; //static integer indicates to show or hide
bool showAd = true; 
public static bool running; //static variable indicates if the plane is destroyed or not
public int gameOverCounter = 0; 

void OnGUI(){
    GUI.skin = skin;

    //if start is not equal to 0 and running is false then show GameOver page buttons
    if ((StartPage.start != 0) && !PlaneMovement.running) {
        gameOverCounter++;

        if (gameOverCounter >= 5) {
            showAd = true;
        if(showAd){ //Check if we should show add 
            if (Advertisement.IsReady ()) {
                Advertisement.Show ();
                showAd = false; 
                    gameOverCounter = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2.378f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6f, Screen.height / 10.10f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Restart"))) {  
            SceneManager.LoadScene (1);  

            PlaneMovement.running = true;
        }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 1.50f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6.0f, Screen.height / 10.1f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Home"))) {
            SceneManager.LoadScene (0);  
            PlaneMovement.running = false;
            StartPage.start = 0;
        }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 5.7f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6f, Screen.height / 10.10f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Website"))) {
            Application.OpenURL ("http://www.skyboxertech.weebly.com");
        }


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnGUI()` function is called **several** times per **frame**. As long as `StartPage.start` is **not** **0** and `PlaneMovement.running` is **not** **true**
your add will always show. Those two **conditions** are **met**. That's why the ads are **showing**. I don't know what those variables are and what you use them for but its a good idea to display your ad every **5 time** the game is over instead of **each time** the game is opened. It is **annoying** and will make players **delete** your game.

You can create a boolean variable called `showAdd` that determines when to display ad. The code below will show ad once.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

//GameOver page when the plane is destroyed
public class GameOverPage : MonoBehaviour {

public GUISkin skin; //skin for button styles
public static int start; //static integer indicates to show or hide
bool showAd = true; //Will show ad the first time
public static bool running; //static variable indicates if the plane is destroyed or not


void OnGUI(){
            GUI.skin = skin;

            //if start is not equal to 0 and running is false then show GameOver page buttons
        if ((StartPage.start != 0) && !PlaneMovement.running) {
          if(showAd){ //Check if we should show add           
            if (Advertisement.IsReady ()) {
            Advertisement.Show ();
            showAd = false; //Set to false So that we dont show ad again
          }
      }


        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 2.378f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6f, Screen.height / 10.10f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Restart"))) {  
                            Application.LoadLevel (1);  
                            PlaneMovement.running = true;
                    }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 1.50f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6.0f, Screen.height / 10.1f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Home"))) {
                            Application.LoadLevel (0);  
                            PlaneMovement.running = false;
                            StartPage.start = 0;
                    }
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (Screen.width / 5.7f, Screen.height / 1.34f, Screen.width / 6f, Screen.height / 10.10f), "", skin.GetStyle ("Website"))) {
                            Application.OpenURL ("http://www.skyboxertech.weebly.com");
                    }


        }
    }
}
```

You can then have a **integer variable** that **counts** how **many times** game has been over. if it reaches 5, set **showAdd** to **true** and ad will **show** again.

Comment: how would I implement the integer variable

Comment: Come back when you write your first game and I will provided that. Right now I will try to explain. Create a variable a variable called gameOverCounter and initialize it to 0. When the game is over, increment gameOverCounter by 1 by doing gameOverCounter ++ or gameOverCounter = gameOverCounter+1. Then use if statement to check if gameOverCounter  is >= 5. If it is, reset gameOverCounter  to zero and then enable ad by setting showAd  to true. After the ad is displayed, set showAd  to false so that it wont display again. This should happen over and over again. Hope I explained it well.

Comment: You are on the right track. The problem is that where you put gameOverCounter++; is always true.Because of this, gameOverCounter++; is always run without stopping and causing your add show all the time.  Put gameOverCounter++; in a function that detects when your game is over. Learn C# and Unity API on Youtube and follow  a complete simple game tutorial then you will understand very much of what I am saying.